# WCF REST Security Impersonation

Tags: c#, wcf, security

I have the website in IIS7 setup with Enable Windows Authentication.

I have 3 methods in my service, 2 methods require Windows Authentication and 1 does not.  The one that does not is using

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
```

The other 2 are using

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
```

My web.config looks like:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</modules>
<security>
  <authentication>
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true"/>
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
  </authentication>
</security>


 </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </standardEndpoint>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When I run try to execute the method that is set to Allowed and I don't pass any credentials, it fails with an Unauthorized error.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You still need to provide credentials when using 
`[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]`

[Allowed: Impersonation is performed if credentials are available and ImpersonateCallerForAllOperations is equal to true.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.impersonationoption%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Have you tried setting ImpersonateCallerForAllOperations to false?